# Netsuite: Populate Field with Items based on Chosen Transaction (Purchase Order)

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way to filter the Items that are listed in a field by the selected Purchase Order (transaction), ie user selects a purchase order, that then populates the Item field with a list of items on that purchase order?

Sorry if this is a really easy question, but I have searched all over the place, and I can't find exactly this scenario. Can't find it in the documentation, either. I'll keep trying, but if anyone knows off-hand, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's possible using script. How do you envision this "Item" field to work? As freetext with a comma separated list of items? Or a multiselect? Or a select?

Comment: A select, if possible. Basically, the user will select a Purchase Order that is relevant to this new record, and then the user needs to choose which Item on the PO is being tested (the new record is a quality test record). I can filter the transactions to show just Purchase orders, but I can't get a second select box to go into the items on that PO and list those items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using Suitescript.

You need to dynamically insert a custom select field to the form on `beforeLoad` using a User Event script, lets call it `custpage_mycustomfield`.

Then you need a clientscript that populates the list of items  on `custpage_mycustomfield`, this needs to happen after the PO field has been changed. You can run a search or load the record to get the line items.

The data you enter in `custpage_mycustomfield` won't be saved, so if you want to preserve it you need to do the following:

1. Create a custom field using the UI that is of type of List/Record > 
   Item, lets call it `custbody_mypermanentfield`
2. Set a clientscript function to run on `saveRecord` that will copy the 
   value selected from `custpage_mycustomfield` to `custbody_mypermanentfield`.

Answer (score 1):

All of this can be done from clientscript on `fieldChanged` event of PO field. First, apply search on PO and get all the sublist item list and then remove all select options of item field and then add the PO's sublist item list on this field.

```
function fieldChanged(context){
var currRec = context.currentRecord;

// search on PO to get sublist items
var itemSearch = search.create({
    type: 'purchaseorder',
    filter: ['internalid', 'is', '<your PO id>'],
    columns: ['item']
}).run().getRange(0,100);

var poItemList = [];
itemSearch.forEach(function(result){
    if (result.getValue({name: 'item'})) {
        poItemList.push = { value: result.getValue({name: 'item'}), text: result.getText({name: 'item'})};
}
})

//remove all options of item field
var itemField = currRec.getField({fieldId: '<your custom field>'});
itemField.removeSelectOption({value: null}) //this removes all options

//add sublist items in item field options
poItemList.forEach(function(item){
    itemField.addSelectOption(item);
})}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but I think a more robust solution would be using the saved search filter available on the custom form.

From the admin center --> Customization --> Forms --> Transaction Forms --> "Your Form" --> Edit

Under the sublist fields tab is a dropdown menu of item searches. You would just select a search that limits the drop down based on your needs.